# Riddle: Come ponder with me

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Come ponder with me, as we go forth,
How we behave in a manner of worth.

With a single change, that worth is no more.
Instead we consider the ones before.

After one more change, seen with different eyes,
We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

To solve my riddle thoroughly,
You'll need to give me answers three.

#### Hint 1

> You are looking for three words that can be changed into each other according to the instructions in the poem.

#### Hint 2

> The first line of the poem is meant only as an introduction.  "Going forth" is not a clue to the word you're looking for.

#### Hint 3

> I'm looking for 3 adverbs, of 10 letters each.

Comment: I'll ponder with you, but will you ponder with me too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are

> PRECIOUSLY, PREVIOUSLY, GRIEVOUSLY

*Come ponder with me, as we go forth,

 How we behave in a manner of worth.*

> **Preciously** means "of high cost or worth".

*With a single change, that worth is no more.

 Instead we consider the ones before.*

> Change the **c** to a **v** to get **previously**, meaning "earlier or coming before"

*After one more change, seen with different eyes,

 We behave in a way we won't trivialize.*

> Change the **p** to a **g** and move the **i** (seen with different "eyes") to get **grievously**, which means "serious or dire" (not trivial).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Many others provided great answers, though, so congratulations to all!

Answer (score 13):

The answers are

> PROCESSION, PRECESSION, PRECISION

*Come ponder with me, as we go forth,

 How we behave in a manner of worth.*

> We "go forth" in a **procession**, perhaps a carnival or festival of "worth".

*With a single change, that worth is no more.

 Instead we consider the ones before.*

> Change a single letter to get **precession**, meaning preceding or "going before".

*After one more change, seen with different eyes,

 We behave in a way we won't trivialize.*

> Change the word again by introducing a new I ("eye); precision is not to be sniffed at and "trivialised"!

*To solve my riddle thoroughly,

 You'll need to give me answers three.*

> Indeed: three similar words.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I had in mind three different words, so I'll wait to see if anyone is able to come up with those.  If not, you definitely deserve credit for finding 3 different words that still seem to (generally) fit the riddle!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Is it close? If he changed the first word to "recession", it would have a better link to worth, with the other two words remaining the same.

Comment: @IanMacDonald  No, none of the three words given by rand al'thor were what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a little too simplistic, but food for thought if nothing else:

> **Cost**, **Lost**, and **List**

How we behave in a manner of worth.

> Something's worth is often considered its **cost**

With a single change, that worth is no more.
 Instead we consider the ones before.

> One letter change (**C** to **L**), and we get **lost**, perhaps referring to those that have died, and therefore came before.

After one more change, seen with different eyes,
 We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> Probably the weakest of the three, one more letter change (**O** to **I**) and we get **list**, and if we have a list, it often isn't trivial.

Comment: Again, not the correct answer.  But good try!

Comment: Sounds good! +1. Edit: just saw the OP's comment. I'd thought this was the intended answer before that!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answers are

> **Reflect, Deflect, Reelect**

Come ponder with me, as we go forth,
How we behave in a manner of worth.

> That's **reflect**ing!

Instead we consider the ones before.

> When you vote the ones before, you **reelect** them!

We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> **Deflect**ion isn't a trivial physical phenomenon.

Comment: Good attempt, but I think the answers are reaching a little.  Not the words I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

***Note***: this one feels pretty weak.

How we behave in a manner of worth.

> Many people are ***sour*** about their worth being questioned.

With a single change, that worth is no more.

> Change the s to a t.

Instead we consider the ones before.

> When you ***tour*** a museum, you consider artifacts and events from the past.

After one more change, seen with different eyes,

> Change the u to an i and read it backwards.

We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> People ***riot*** when they are emphatic about their cause being not trivialised.

Comment: A worthy attempt, but not what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three 10-letter adverbs.

How we behave in a manner of worth.

> [**vauntingly**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vauntingly): we boast about our worth.

With a single change, that worth is no more.
Instead we consider the ones before.

> [**hauntingly**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hauntingly): ghosts were people before.

After one more change, seen with different eyes,
We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> [**tauntingly**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tauntingly): it isn't easy to trivialise or ignore a taunt.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that my riddle did not provide sufficient information for a unique solution, based on the plethora of good answers that are not what I intended.  This is good, but not what I was thinking.

Comment: No worries. I think that it's pretty neat that there are so many different solutions to what seems to be a very specific set of requirements, though it is technically against the puzzle construction guidelines of this site.

Answer (score 1):

***Note***: I'm being rather liberal with the requirements here, and maybe thinking too far outside the box.

How we behave in a manner of worth.

> **$1m** is short-hand for "one million dollars", which is worth a lot.

With a single change, that worth is no more.

> Remove the m and we have **$1**, where the worth is no more.

Instead we consider the ones before.

> We consider the 1 as it is the only digit left.

After one more change, seen with different eyes,

> Adding an i is a change and shown with different "eyes" (as a homonym).

We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> **$1i** is a complex number and therefore cannot be trivialised.

Comment: Yes, you're thinking too far outside the box.  Good effort, though!

Answer (score 1):

Not confident of this, but here is my answer:

> The base word is *form* -- **formation, former, reform (or transform)**

How we behave in a manner of worth.

> This is probably connected to the word hierarchy or ranking, so I choose the word *formation*

With a single change, that worth is no more.
Instead we consider the ones before.

> *former* I think these lines mean a word pertaining to *past*

After one more change, seen with different eyes,
We behave in a way we won't trivialize.

> these lines are about change, *transform* or *reform* is synonymous to change.

Comment: Another good try, but not the desired answer.